# ASP.NET MVC CTP (first version) fails uninstalling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, uninstallation, visual-studio-addins

The offending command that msi executes is:

```
 .\devenv.com /command "View.Toolbox" /setup
```

This fails with Date execution prevention error.

devenv.exe log contains a bunch of errors like this:

```
 <entry>
    <record>120</record>
    <time>2008/10/21 12:32:01.277</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio Appid Stub</source>
    <description>CheckPackageSignature failed; invalid Package Load Key</description>
    <guid>{0C6E6407-13FC-4878-869A-C8B4016C57FE}</guid>
  </entry>
```

And ends with:

```
 <entry>
    <record>122</record>
    <time>2008/10/21 12:32:05.817</time>
    <type></type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio</source>
    <description>Destroying Main Window</description>
  </entry>
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with msiexec and forcing update/uninstall and uninstallation of clone detective (for VS.NET) solved this problem .

Answer (score 0):

Have you sent this information to the developers of the MVC framework?
I assume that they are glad for information like this.

Comment: It is first CTP, almost a year old. I want to upgrade to newly released beta. Strangely, I had no problems with previous CTPs.